# Flutter Provider: notifyListeners() not working in async function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

notifyListeners() is not working when called inside Future function. The values are updated but the widget does not rebuild.

```
Future<void> main() async {
      runApp(
        MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AuthProvider()),
            ...
          ],
          child: const App(),
        ),
      );
    }

class AuthProvider with ChangeNotifier, DiagnosticableTreeMixin {
  AuthStatus _status = AuthStatus.uninitialized;
  JwtToken? _jwtToken;

  AuthStatus get status => _status;

  JwtToken? get jwtToken => _jwtToken;

  AuthProvider() {
    init();
  }

  init() async {
    _jwtToken = await getJwtToken();

    if (_jwtToken != null) {
      if (!JwtDecoder.isExpired(_jwtToken!
              .accessToken)) {              
        _status = AuthStatus.authenticated;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        _refreshLogin();
      }
    } else {
      _status = AuthStatus.unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  _refreshLogin() async {
    _status = AuthStatus.authenticating;
    notifyListeners();
     ...
      _status = AuthStatus.authenticated;    
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

  login(String username, String password) async {
    _status = AuthStatus.authenticating;
    notifyListeners();    
    ...
      _status = AuthStatus.authenticated;    
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I'm calling the function.

```
await context.read<AuthProvider>().login(_username!, _password!);
```

I also tried this

```
await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context,listen: false).login(_username!, _password!);
```

The login function is excecated but notifyListeners() does not rebuild the widget